# Blogger edit HTML template code no working

Tags: html, blogger, html-editor

I'm adding custom code into my Blogger site for a share button, and what's strange is that when I update the HTML code in the Template HTML Editor, the chagnes are not made live.

I go into the HTML Editor, make my changes, Save Template, go to the live blog and the old code is still there.

I go back to the HTML Editor and my changes are still saved inside the editor.

Can anyone help me understand why the changes are not seen live? I've waited 24 hours to see if was some kind of delay, but it's still the same situation, in the HTML Editor the new code is there, on the live blog, the old code is there.

Comment: can i have ur blog url.....try clearing cookies cache etc as well and then retrying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bit silly, but the issue was that there was actually two copies of the same code.

Blogger's HTML editor automatically hides large sections of code into carrots and I mistakenly was editing the incorrect code. So changes were made, code was updated, and the live code was different because it was a completely different section of the actual HTML template.